# i want to add time in addition to date (elixir) so how can i edit the input so i it can be added the time too?

Tags: elixir

So here is the code from this webpage:
https://github.com/sasa1977/elixir-in-action/tree/master/code_samples/ch06
i want to add time into the list, which the date already exist, if possible please help me edit it so i can know what is the different befire and after, thanks for the help.

part of the code in list.exs

```
def entries(todo_list, date) do
    todo_list.entries
    |> Stream.filter(fn {_, entry} -> entry.date == date end)
    |> Enum.map(fn {_, entry} -> entry end)
  end
```

part of the code in server.exs

```
 def entries(todo_server, date) do
    GenServer.call(todo_server, {:entries, date})
  end

  @impl GenServer
  def handle_call({:entries, date}, _, {name, todo_list}) do
    {
      :reply,
      Todo.List.entries(todo_list, date),
      {name, todo_list}
    }
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly add a new key/value `time` to the map using the `Time` module, when you create a new entry.

Try this in IEx:

```
> {:ok, todo_server} = TodoServer.start()
{:ok, #PID<0.121.0>}

> date = Date.utc_today
~D[2020-05-17]

>{:ok, time} = Time.new(10, 30, 0)
{:ok, ~T[10:30:00]}

> TodoServer.add_entry(todo_server, %{date: date, time: time, title: "learn Elixir"})
[%{date: ~D[2020-05-17], id: 1, time: ~T[10:30:00], title: "learn Elixir"}]
```

Then you'll be able to filter the entries not only by date, but also by time. You could add this new function clause in your list.exs file :

```
def entries(todo_list, date, time) do
    todo_list.entries
    |> Stream.filter(fn {_, entry} -> entry.date == date and entry.time == time end)
    |> Enum.map(fn {_, entry} -> entry end)
 end
```

And those ones in your server.exs file:

```
def entries(todo_server, date, time) do
    GenServer.call(todo_server, {:entries, date, time})
end

@impl GenServer
def handle_call({:entries, date, time}, _, {name, todo_list}) do
    {
      :reply,
      Todo.List.entries(todo_list, date, time),
      {name, todo_list}
    }
end
```

Let me know how it worked out for you in the end!